# QGIS Convert vector classification map into raster

Tags: qgis, raster, vector, rasterization

I tried to convert vector classification into raster file for accuracy analysis [following these suggestions](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/137038/how-to-convert-a-vector-map-to-raster-in-qgis)

My vector data is like this:

[image]

However, none works
The first one, interpolation, resulting in .asc file which is invisible with zero value.

[image]
[image]

The second one I tried to use rasterize function, it loaded, but nothing happen, the output is not change. I tried to follow this [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oVaUzsbjPNs) by copying style, but the raster layer become invisible.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Hmm, it's just a guess: is there a tiny polgon feature selected, and are you trying to rasterize one single small feature? Cellsize and X/Y min/max values in the 2nd image look strange. 300x300 cells of size 0, covering an area of about 100x100 meters? (if coordinates are in degrees)

Comment: No, i didn't select any features, and trying to rasterize the whole image

Comment: cellsize 0.00000 ?

Comment: i tried to put cellsize x and y as 1.0, and number of row and collumn 1000. the result is a raster file with "NAN" value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the input file is a shapefile and you need to convert your data from vector to raster, I think what you need to do is to select "raster size in pixels" and specify the desired output pixel size as you can see in the image below:

[image]

Comment: it works :D thanks. I tried to put 10000 in the raster size and it is work. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

I am one of the authors of the video tutorial that you mentioned.

Just to see, try giving the row and line number using braster size in pixel. 
Or try processing using the grass tools v.to.rast
Maybe you could upload the shape for testing?

Comment: It works now. I have to choose raster size in pixel. thanks